# amazon web services startup

Tags: scripting, amazon-web-services, startup

How should I script my application(a C# console application), to run at the virtual machine start-up?

Should I use shell scripts or something else?

What should the structure of the script file be like?

Thanks, Catalin

Comment: Console application implies that you will manually start the program each time. Yes/no? ... I assume that Amazon provides some feature like Linux crontab. That would be my preference. Then you can set it up like 59 23 * * * { /path/to/myConsoleApp(.exe) > /tmp/dailyLog 2>&1.

Comment: .... This captures any (unintentional) output to a file that you can check every day. I can provide further detail about makng keeping hists of /tmp/dailyLog.trace files.  A script can help if you need to set different ENV vars (based on PROD/QA/DEV, etc) or setup input params to your prog AND should capture output as above (IHMO ;-)  For sturcture, you just want step1, step2, ... stepN (with approriate env vars generalizing inputs, paths, etc. Post with tags=bash and you'll get answers almost immediately. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy you exe file in the Startup folder (Start->All Programs->Startup, right click->open)

Answer (score -1):

You might try using SrvStart. SrvStart allows you to run any application as a Windows Service. While the vast majority of applications are not suited for this type of deployment (i.e. Notepad, Microsoft Word, etc.), there are lots of utilities which can run seamlessly as a background service. By interfacing with the Windows Service Manager, SrvStart “interprets” the Operating System commands, such as start (open) and stop (close), and sends them to the target application which doesn’t know the difference.

Here is an article that might be a useful starting place: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Comment: Use SrvStart if you want the program to run at boot.  Use the Startup folder if you want the program to run at login.

Comment: You should summarize and explain the link in this answer.